# Choosing CIDR blocks

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, subnet, cidr

I am struggling to understand CIDR blocks in the way I am using them. My understanding is (probably wrong) that they are a way of reserving a range of IP addresses for your environment, and you can apportion them across applications. But I can't get it working in my case. I am using terraform to manage a simple environment. A VPC containing a Lambda and an RDS instance. The RDS will not be publicly accessible, the lambda will be invoked by an HTTP trigger. Each of the Lambda and RDS instance need their own subnets, the RDS needs two. I have this configuration in terraform which keeps failing with this and similar errors:

`The new Subnets are not in the same Vpc as the existing subnet group`

The terraform set up is:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Name = "vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "rds_subnet_1a" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"

  tags = {
    Name = "rds_subnet_1a"

  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "rds_subnet_1b" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.2.0/24"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-1b"

  tags = {
    Name = "rds_subnet_1b"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "lambda_subnet_1a" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.3.0/24"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"

  tags = {
    Name = "lambda_subnet_1a"
  }
}


resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "default" {
  name       = "main"
  subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.rds_subnet_1a.id, aws_subnet.rds_subnet_1b.id]
  tags = {
    Name = "My DB subnet group"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "rds" {
  name   = "rds-sg"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 5432
    to_port     = 5432
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 5432
    to_port     = 5432
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "rds-sg"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "lambda" {
  name   = "lambda_sg"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    protocol  = -1
    self      = true
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "lambda_sg"
  }
}
```

I know this is basic, but I just think if I get some answers to my situation it may help me understand the concepts better.

EDIT - lambda config:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "api_uprn" {
  function_name = "api-uprn"

  s3_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lambdas_bucket.id
  s3_key    = "api-uprn/function_0.0.8.zip"

  runtime = "python3.9"
  handler = "app.main.handler"

  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = [aws_subnet.subnet_1a.id]
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.lambda.id]

  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "api_uprn" {
  name = "/aws/lambda/${aws_lambda_function.api_uprn.function_name}"

  retention_in_days = 30
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_exec" {
  name = "api_uprn"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [{
      Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
      Effect = "Allow"
      Sid    = ""
      Principal = {
        Service = "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      }
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "rds_read" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonRDSReadOnlyAccess"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_vpc_access" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
}
```

Comment: Which subnet should Lambda reside in? 1a?

Comment: yes, `lambda_subnet_1a`. Then the RDs should be in either `rds_subnet_1b` and `rds_subnet_1a`

Comment: Ok then, you don't need a third subnet. You can just tell Lambda which existing subnet to use. Is there any code for the Lambda resource?

Comment: I think I already have 3, no?

Comment: What does that mean? If you need RDS and Lambda in the same subnet then you need to use one of those that were created. Not a new one.

Comment: ah sorry, I misread your comment. I will give that a go.

Comment: I have added the terraform for the lambda now

Answer (score 1):

Can you please post here, the full error? It will be easier to understand what state is throwing the error!

My tip is that you need to change your `subnet_ids` at your lambda configuration. From what I understand, your lambda configuration should be like this:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "api_uprn" {
  function_name = "api-uprn"

  s3_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lambdas_bucket.id
  s3_key    = "api-uprn/function_0.0.8.zip"

  runtime = "python3.9"
  handler = "app.main.handler"

  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = [aws_subnet. lambda_subnet_1a.id]
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.lambda.id]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I fixed the problem just by swapping the CIDR block from `10.0.3.0/24` to `10.0.4.0/24`. I am not really sure if that's the correct solution, but it did work..

Comment: Hum, that should not be the correct solution. Did you search your subnets if `10.0.3.0/24` are in use?

Comment: The CIDR assigned to each subnet are `10.0.4.0/24`, `10.0.2.0/24`,`10.0.1.0/24`] I was just going to increment the third space by 1 for each different subnet. I think `10.0.3.0/24` doesnt come under `10.0.0.0/16`, which is the CIDR block for the VPC I created

Comment: `10.0.0.0/16` goes from `10.0.0.0/24` until `10.0.255.0/24` so that is not the issue. But if you find my comments/answer helpful please vote it up 